# identifier expected or '(' for referenced pod(MegicalRecord) IOS xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I have error while building project :

[image]

In pods I have megicalRecords library , and pods are building successfuly but when I build my project I have error as shown in image i.e. Expected Identifier or '('. Can anyone please help what is issue exactally as I am new in ios development, not able to figure out the issue yet.

Following is CoreData+MegicalRecord.h code

[image]

On clicking issue naigator moves to the following screen.
[image]

Comment: That usually means you have a syntax error. Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Just have added CoreData+MegicalRecords.h file

Comment: When you click on the warning in the Issue Navigator, it should bring you to the exact line that is causing the problem. Can you post that?

Comment: It points out the CoreData+MegicalRecord.h as shown in first figure;

Comment: Click the "Parse Issue." In the first figure it looks like you've clicked the .h file itself.

Comment: Just added new snapshot

Comment: Thanks mate, got figured out, pods were not updated.